# Use input as basis of what date to display excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, time

I need a way to use the input on a userform to determine the date that will be displayed on the output. Here's my code:

```
If StatusBox.Value <= "23:59" And ShiftCode.Value = "AA5" Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = ((Date - 1) + " " + StatusBox.Value + " " + "CEST")
Else
    Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = (Date + " " + StatusBox.Value + " " + "CEST")
End If
```

Basically I need the date to be displayed as `Date - 1` when the input from StatusBox.Value is less than or equal to `11:59 PM or 23:59` the inputs on the `StatusBox` field will always be in the 12-Hour format.

Comment: Ive edited the question. Im trying to say that both inputs will be numbers in the 12-hour time format and the range they would have would be from 00:00 to 23:59

Comment: I've stated the reason why I made the edit.

Comment: Reverted question vandalism, and voting to delete as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Subtract the lower time value from the higher time value, as in `elapsedTime = endTime - startTime'. Don't mess around with text strings, formatting and concatenation until you have the result.

Comment: Will try this solution later, but I need a more urgent help with my new question, I have edited my old one. Thanks